# How to set a primary key on a table correctly?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm a bit confused, all tablets I've seen (I haven't seen many) have an auto-increment field as their primary key.

Is this the best way to set a primary key?

For example, I have the following tables called `Assets` for inventory and I don't know the best way to set the field as a primary key

Ask:
I don't know whether to set an auto-increment field (`indentity`) as a primary key or set the `code` field as a primary key

**Way one**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Asset_A
(
    code INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(150),
    PRIMARY KEY(code)
);
```

**Way two**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Asset_B
(
    id INT IDENTITY,
    code INT NOT NULL, -- BUT THIS IS THE CODE OF ASSET. For SECOND PK?
    name VARCHAR(150),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

The `code` field is a numeric field where a unique ID is set for this asset
example:
name: iPhone 10
code: 1000
etc..

**example of tables with data:**

```sql
GO
INSERT INTO Asset_A
    (code,name)
VALUES
    (1000, 'iphone 10'),
    (1001, 'iphone 11'),
    (1002, 'iphone 12'),
    (1003, 'Samsung Galaxy S8'),
    (1004, 'Samsung Galaxy S9'),
    (1005, 'Samsung Galaxy S10');
GO
INSERT INTO Asset_B
    (code,name)
VALUES
    (1000, 'iphone 10'),
    (1001, 'iphone 11'),
    (1002, 'iphone 12'),
    (1003, 'Samsung Galaxy S8'),
    (1004, 'Samsung Galaxy S9'),
    (1005, 'Samsung Galaxy S10');

GO
SELECT *
FROM Asset_A 

GO
SELECT *
FROM Asset_B

GO
sp_columns Asset_A;
GO
sp_columns Asset_B;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it good to have primary keys as Identity field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720645/is-it-good-to-have-primary-keys-as-identity-field)

Comment: Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932209/identity-column-vs-primary-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not something simple caused by lack of experience. It is a judgement call.

A key that represents an already existing asset is called a "natural" key, in your case, [code]. A system-generated key is called a "surrogate" key, in your case, [id].

Should you use a surrogate key or stick to the natural one? Well, each has its pros and cons, and this is one huge debate for which you will find a plethora of sources. My personal best link is [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5431/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key-differences-and-when-to-use-in-sql-server/). There are other links in the comments, and probably will be in other answers. Search the internet more, too.

If I had to go out of my way and choose for you based on my own experience and how much "keyworthy" I find your [code] to be, I would indeed use [code] over a surrogate. But, this is subjective. Read, study, practice, and these types of judgement calls will come easier.

Answer (score 0):

The Primary Key *must* be unique within the table, and there is no such thing as a second Primary Key in the same table.  You can have another unique non-clustered index, but not a second Primary Key.  In this case, if `code` is guaranteed unique across all other columns in every row, it will work as a Primary Key and you won't need the `IDENTITY` column.

I would recommend doing some additional research on primary keys and how to choose them.  It's certainly not the case that a column with `IDENTITY` set has to be the primary key.  However, there are limitations, such as the PK in SQL Server can be no larger than 900 bytes.